# use scatteredInterpolant variable in embedded matlab function in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is there any way to do i.e.

```
Surface = scatteredInterpolant(measurement_xz(:,1)*1E-3,measurement_xz(:,2)*1E-3,measurement_xz(:,3));
```

where `measurement_xz` is some data in a startup script for my simulink model and then use `Surface` in an embedded matlab function in the simulink model, i.e.

///embedded matlab function

```
function V = fcn(x,z)
V = Surface(x,z);
```

?
When I i.e. try to use `Surface` as a parameter for `V` like

```
function V = fcn(x,z,Surface)
V = Surface(x,z);
```

with `Surface` set as parameter in the Ports and data manager I get the error

*Expression 'Surface' for initial value of data 'Surface' must
evaluate to a numeric or logical*.

Comment: What is a embedded matlab function, I never heard of it. I assume you are talking about one of these: A callback function, an "interpreted MATLAB function" block or a "MATLAB function" block?

Comment: I meant the matlab function block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not supported by the Matlab Function block, MATLAB is unable to generate code for it. The problems are:

- You are trying to access the variable `Surface` which is not visible in the scope
- `scatteredInterpolant` is not supported at all for code generation (at least in my MATLAB version, might be improved in recent Versions).

To fix this on a code level, you could switch to interpreted MATLAB code. This can be done either switching to a Interpreded MATLAB block or using `coder.extrinsic`. It is a quick and simple fix, but I recommend not to do this because it will probably result in a slow model. Instead I recommend to switch to a [lookup table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/lookuptabledynamic.html), which is also capable of interpolating.